# John Wick asking for laundry

Tags: analysis, john-wick

There are several codes in John Wick's assassin society. One of these is asking for *dinner reservations*, a codename for body-disposal services.

As John comes to the Hotel after the Red Circle club scene, he has this conversation with the *concierge*:

> How good's your laundry?
>
> I'm sorry to say no one is that good.
>
> No. I thought not.

**Is John actually asking for laundry for his blood-stained clothes? Or is this some code for some service?** It seems silly that his concern at the moment is whether his shirt is decent or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, he's literally asking about laundry.**

Here's a more complete segment of the script, for reference:

> The lobby is empty -save the Manager- who glances up from his
>   computer... to find a wounded -and quite bloody- John walking towards
>   him.
>
> MANAGER: (without blinking) Good evenin’, sir.
>
> JOHN: Evenin’. Is the doctor in?
>
> MANAGER: Yes, sir. Twenty-four/seven.
>
> JOHN: Send him up, please.
>
> MANAGER: Yes, sir. Anything else, sir?
>
> JOHN: Depends. How good’s your laundry?
>
> MANAGER: The best, sir, however, I’m sorry to say that... no one’s that good.
>
> John chuckles, sliding a gold coin across to the Manager.
>
> JOHN: No, I thought not.

So, in this scene John is injured and asking for the hotel's live-in doctor (a literal request, not a code - to patch up his wounds.)  This is a service that I expect many professional assassins in this world would need, so it makes sense that the Continental would offer one.

The manager *asks if he needs anything else.*  He doesn't really, but since the manager asked, he inquires about the laundry to deal with his bloody clothing.  He's not too surprised at the answer, of course.  He was asking partly - if not entirely - in jest.